# Bad Persian character connection IranNastaliq font GDI

Tags: c#, gdi+, text-rendering

I rendered Persian word "یک" to bitmap using method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63720333/10600811) and IranNastaliq font:
[image]
As you can see, there is a broken part between "یـ" and "ک" which doesn't exist when using same font in other apps (WordPad, GIMP, Paint, etc.). Why it is rendered like this and is there any solution?