# overlaid parts of text get transparent GDI+

Tags: c#, gdi+, text-rendering

I run this code:

```cs
graphics.DrawString("( پنج)", new Font(IranNastaliq, 77), ...);
```

which results in:
[image]
As you can see, circled parts are overlaid and turned transparent. Why those parts get transparent and how should I prevent it?

Comment: Looks like a Font error to me. - You could try `TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, ...)`

Comment: @TaW Overlays are caused by font but there are no transparencies in other apps. Also, `TextRenderer` solved the problem but rendered text needs antialiasing. I can't find how should I enable antialiasing for `TextRenderer`.

Comment: Antialiasing  . This ought to be done by setting the properties of the Graphics object it takes. I have a hunch that graphics.DrawString get confused and creates a wrong GraphicsPath in the process. Is it just the holes or is the whole shape wrong? GraphicsPath.AddText would be another option which would let you test tw o WindingMOdes. -  TextRenderer is recommended for everything except(!!) printing..

Comment: @TaW I set properties of Graphics object like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63720333/10600811). However, `TextRenderer` still generate jagged texts.

Comment: Maybe setting the [TextContrast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.textcontrast?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) lower would help?

Comment: @TaW I changed many properties of my Graphics object but `TextRenderer` doesn't care at all! It always render the same.