# Render antialiased text using TextRenderer C#

Tags: c#, gdi, antialiasing, text-rendering

I wrote a program to draw some string on an image. I use `graphics.DrawString()` but as you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63816737/10600811) post, it has some problems.
`TextRenderer.DrawText()` solved that problem but the rendered text is jagged. I changed both `graphics.TextRenderingHint` and resolution of graphics; `TextRenderer` doesn't care at all.
There should be a solution as it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23230570/10600811); but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Reading second link, looks like you have to set font quality manually? Graphics object properties (GDI+) do not affect Textrenderer (GDI) - or that is how I understand linked information.

Comment: @Arvo How should I set font quality?

Comment: I have no idea, this is just what I understood from linked discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //GDI (i.e. TextRenderer)
            String s = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
            Point origin = new Point(11, 11);
            Font font = SystemFonts.IconTitleFont;

            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;

            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, s, font, origin, SystemColors.InfoText);
        }
```

Full demo showing that it **does** work: https://mega.nz/file/E3xREYIR#kuDxyac_0jxlX7wuTVmZmJgClEicdaCj0YpnE83Wq9k

Comment: You're right. However effect of these properties are really low on this font (IranNastaliq). I couldn't detect the difference between different `TextRenderingHint` modes for `TextRenderer` at first. Only a few (maybe less than 10) pixels are different between all modes. Also, when I increase font size, the [overlapping problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63816737/10600811) appears again even using `TextRenderer`.